# Error: loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content PRESTASHOP jQuery

Tags: http, ssl, https, prestashop

The page at 'https://www.webpage.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://www.webpage.com/theme/images/image.png?6561645': 
this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
How can I solve this problem?